# Is there a way I can set up an alert when data source Azure SQL tables is not updated with latest date?

Tags: azure, data-quality

Recently I have been notified by my report users that the report data is not updated. Then only when I checked the data source, I found out that data source data isn't synced in yet.

Because there are many tables, I cannot manually check one table at a time, every day.

I would like to know if there is a solution where I can get alert that the data source is not synced, or the source table is not updated with the latest data? So that I can be proactive in fixing the problem.

Comment: Hey! I'm working on this lightweight library: https://github.com/SuperiorityComplex/data_checks where you can write simple Python code to check your data and run it at a predefined schedule (with alerting and other features)